# Search for multiple files within Wordpress Media Library

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to search for multiple images/files within the WordPress Media Library?

I've search all over Google for this and I don't see that anyone has asked this question before or that a custom function code available in general.

I'd appreciate any help.

- Jane

Comment: Your question is very vague. Search how? By a shell command line?

Comment: A manual search by going to Admin > Media and using the built in search bar.

Comment: The Wordpress search bar returns  wildcard matches (MySQL "LIKE '%searchterm%' " ) so the answer is no using  the WP default search query. You might be able to find a plugin that will do what you need.

Comment: Before posting my question here, I also checked for plugins to no avail. Thanks anyway, I appreciate your input.

Comment: That is not to say the multi words searches are not possible. If you're a programmer you can modify a search plugin [like this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-search-enhanced/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I'm not a programmer but I'll see if I can figure something out.